# how to parse nested json data in django, if the json data has nested data, how to read one by one?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
{
    "slug": {
        "bigbazar":[1,2,3],
        "paytm":[4,5,6],
        "wallmart":[7,8,9],
        "more":[10,11,12],
        "spencers":[14,15,16]
    },
    "technical":{
        "tech_summary":true,
        "marketing_summary":true,
        "consolidate":true
    },
    "inspection":{
        "t003":{
            "download":"pdf"
        },
        "t005":{
            "download":"pdf"
        },
        "t011":true,
        "consolidate":true
    },
    "records":{
        "sale_report":true,

        "stock_report":true,

        "audit_doc":{
            "download":"pdf",
        "consolidate":true
        }
    },
    "maintenance":"stacks",

    "contracts":{
        "invoice":{
            "download":"pdf"
        },
        "unit_sum":{
            "download":"pdf"
        },
        "unit_his":{
            "download":"pdf"
        },
        "cash_flow":{
            "download":"pdf"
        },
        "BDA":{
            "download":"pdf"
        },
        "hire":true,

        "inv_audit":{
            "download":"pdf"
        },
        "consolidate":true
    }
}
```

The above JSON file I received through POST method from front-end. How to extract the code of each?

for each slug:
    if bigbazar slug= [1,.2,3]:

```
def (request, slug):
     for each slug in bigbazar
        if inspection=true
              if t003(download=pdf)
                   (genarate pdf code)
              else
                   (genarate docx code)
```

like for all the requested item i have to generate the code as required formate and then i have to zip as below

zip filk(containing foledrs(technical, inspection,records,
et...)

Comment: You can start from reading about [DRF serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: What do you mean by `read the POST`? You already have this data from the request, right? So what exact you want to get next?

Comment: `json.loads(data)` will give you a python object (`dict`) so you can then just use standard python to retrieve the key value pairs. Here's the docs for [json](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/json.html) and [dict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#mapping-types-dict)